# distinct query with autosuggest

Tags: php, mysql, distinct, autosuggest

I'm trying to distinct a column for my autosuggest function. This is the query I have now:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['chars'])."%' ORDER BY firstname LIMIT 0, 10",$con) or die(mysql_error());
```

somehow just adding 'DISTINCT firstname' after select doesn't work. (Javascript gives an error.)
the * in the query is the trouble maker I guess, don't know exactly why..

Please assist with writing the right query! :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use "group by firstname" in stead:

```
$result=mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM users
    WHERE firstname LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['chars'])."%'
    GROUP BY firstname ASC
    ORDER BY firstname
    LIMIT 0, 10",$con)
or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: thanks 1: for the quick reply, thanks 2: for the correct solution, thanks 3: for this website! Thanks a lot :)!

Comment: You're welcome! If the answer was correct you should mark it as such on the page so your question doesn't remain "unanswered".